# How does PHP interpret Javascript's Null value?

Tags: javascript, php

Sol let's suppose that we send a post query to a PHP file, 
this query where we have ...&title=title
where title is for example  `title=$(#title).val();` (assuming we're including Jquery)
 in PHP we have `$title=$_POST['title'];`
Let's suppose then that title is null , will PHP consider null as string  ? or something empty ?

Comment: Nulls are nulls everywhere. Isn't it?

Comment: @xy_: You can not tell a variable is null in php, with the exception of the actual 'value' `NULL`. Trying to set it with any other null-like value will result in an empty string

Comment: `title` won't be null, `val()` always returns a string (assuming you've selected an input)

Comment: Then You just don write anything for the title, 
It'll give undefined , bu then how will php understand undefined  ? 
will $title get "undefined" String as value ?

Comment: I think you mean "interpret" not "compile"

Comment: Yes , sorry , I lost that word !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php):

The special `NULL` value represents a variable with no value. `NULL` is the only possible value of type `NULL`.

A variable is considered to be `NULL` if:

- it has been assigned the constant `NULL`.
- it has not been set to any value yet.
- it has been [unset()](http://php.net/unset).

`"NULL"` is not the same as `NULL`.

```
var_dump("null" == NULL);
```

Outputs:

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: But the thing is this null value is sent from Javascript , it's like 
title=null
then you do a $title=$_POST['title'];
which basically gives $title="null"; 
doesn't it ?

Comment: that is will be like this: `$variable = "null";`, null as a string

Comment: @AymaneShuichi: See the answer. `"NULL" is not the same as NULL`

Comment: @Downvoter: can you suggest any improvements / explain the downvote?

Comment: It would not evaluate to the type NULL, but more a string containing 'null', but in this case, the argument is most likely parsed, but with no value.

Comment: @AymaneShuichi: `the title value is coming from javascript through ajax , if the javascript value is undefined , will php iterpret it as string ?` -- yes. It won't be interpreted as `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

The title gets converted to a string before sending it to the server.

Converting the JS value `null` to a string results in a string `"null"`. Therefore, PHP will only interpret the variable as a string.

However, I doubt that you will receive a *null* value from an empty input box. You will get an empty string instead.

Comment: `$(#title).val();` will probably not evaluate to 'null' unless the element doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, if you send a `$(#title).val();` as data in an ajax request to a php script, and the input is empty, it would just be an empty string.

Comment: what if it returns undefined in Javascript ? 
will $title get the string "undefined" ?

Answer (score 0):

php intercepts js null as "null" -> string, So to handle form request, i had small work around in my php code like below

```
function checknull($arg){
    if($arg == "null"){
      return;
    }else{
        return $arg;
    }
}
$a=array();
$b = "null";
$a['hi'] = checknull($b);
var_dump($a);
```

This will output as

```
array(1) { ["hi"]=> NULL }
```

//same you can test it for $_REQUEST

```
$var1 = checknull($_POST['title']);
var_dump($var1);
```

or you can use

```
$var1 = $_POST['title'] === 'null'? NULL : $_POST['title'];
var_dump($var1);
```